# Is cocoapods.org not working?

Tags: cocoapods

I am trying to get a pod for firebase,but whatever name I type in the search box returns nothing. Is the website not working or? Thanks

[image]

Comment: same here, firefox, safari, chrome all do nothing

Comment: same thing for me.

Comment: Same here on both safari and chrome

Comment: I'm running into this still today. They've closed all the github conversations on the topic, which is unfortunate, I'd love to try and have some community involvement to help them keep search up more consistently.

Comment: cocoapods.org is up now you, and working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a problem that many developers face time to time including myself, but no clear answer is ever given by cocoapods though some issues are opened in their github page. One of the issue opened by x1024 mentions that it could be a failed API call in cocoapods side
Opening the site via http://geopeeker.com it sometimes works properly. Opening it via a tunnelling solution like TunnelBear also works.
It could be a CDN issue where the appropriate headers are stripped.

Please check issue page of cocoapods in github to see if any issue there matches yours. Usually this happens to me once in a while and trying the site after some time it works, waiting has always been helpful for me so far. If you have prolonged problem open an issue in their github page. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: the problem is that it is not working via `pod install` too... so it is not a website problem. It is a server problem.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a particular version of the pod. Sometimes just specifying pod name doesn't install the pod, I've once come across such case, specifying an older version solved the issue for me.

Comment: This happens all the time. So annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the status of the site here
https://status.cocoapods.org

The site search has been down for a few days now.
From the command line do

`pod search POD NAME`

i.e. `pod search motion`